# Opposite sign for voltage

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conventions

I know that
$$V(\vec{P_1})-V(\vec{P_2})=-\int_{\vec{P_1}}^{\vec{P_2}}\vec E \cdot d\vec l$$
but when I apply it to a point $x$ away from a point charge $q$, setting $V=0$ at $\infty$, I get
$$\begin{align}
V(x)-V(\infty)&=-\frac 1{4\pi \epsilon _0}\int_{\infty}^{x}\frac {-q}{t^2} dt \\
V(x)&=-\frac 1{4\pi\epsilon _0}\cdot \frac q x
\end{align}$$
implying that the voltage is the opposite sign as $q$ for all $x$. However, I thought it would be the same sign as $q$ because a positive charge at $x$ would have positive potential energy when $q$ is positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where that extra minus sign of yours comes from.

$$\vec{E}=K\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

So you have

$$V_E=-\int_{r_1}^{r_2} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{r} = -\int_{r_1}^{r_2} K\frac{q}{r^2} dr=-Kq \left[-\frac{1}{r}\right]_{r_1}^{r_2}$$

$$V_E=-Kq \left[-\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_1}\right]$$

If ou make $r_1\rightarrow +\infty$, the second term vanishes and then

$$V_E=-Kq \left[-\frac{1}{r_2}\right]=+K\frac{q}{r_2}\equiv \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r}$$

Comment: Using the case where $q$ is positive, $\hat r$ and $d \vec r$ are in different directions so $\hat r \cdot d\vec r = -dr$ if $dr$ is positive. However, $dr$ is negative in this case because we are integrating from $\infty$ to $r_2$; this was my mistake. Thank you for the input, writing out $\vec E$ in terms of $\hat r$ helped me realise this.

Comment: @AbrahamZhang Um? I think you're wrong man. $\hat{r}$ is **fixed** and it points outwards the change.  If the charge is positive, $q>0$, everything is possitive and then it keeps pointing outwards. If the charge is negative, it points inwards because $q<0$. Charges carry the whole sign, and not $\hat{r}$ or $d\vec{r}$

Comment: (I think we can ignore my statement to use the case where $q$ is positive.) Yes $\hat r$ is fixed, but so is $d\vec r$ - which points in the opposite direction to $\hat r$. So $\hat r \cdot d\vec r < 0$?

Comment: @AbrahamZhang No, $d\vec{r}$ is also pointing outwards. Why do you say it isn't?

Comment: Well I think about $d\vec r$ as being defined to be a piece of the curve that it is summed over, i.e. from $r_1$ to $r_2$, and it makes sense to me that it's in the direction from $r_1$ to $r_2$.

Comment: @AbrahamZhang But that's not the definition. It is the differential of the radius vector from $O$ to an arbitrary point (outwards). $\vec{r}=r\cdot\hat{r}$, so $d\vec{r}=dr\cdot\hat{r}$. Outwards as well.